# Unable to prioritize multiclasses in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

I am trying to execute few test cases using TestNG.I want to prioritize the execution of multiple classes in the testng.xml.
I want to execute the entire class first based on the priority given and then move to the another class.
I have used "group-by-instances="true". but it didn't work.`

Following are the classes i want to execute.

```
package pkg1;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class Class1 {

    @Test(priority=1)
    void pkg111() {
        System.out.println("pkg1 class1 p1");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    void pkg121() {
        System.out.println("pkg1 class1 p4");
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    void pkg131() {
        System.out.println("pkg1 class1 p3");
    }
}
```

Another Class

```
    package pkg1;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Class2 {

        @Test(priority=2)
        void Pkg1c2()
        {
            System.out.println("c2p2");

        }

    }
```

Another one

```
package pkg2;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Class4 {
    @Test(priority = 1)
    void pkg211() {
        System.out.println("pkg2 class4 p1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    void pkg221() {
        System.out.println("pkg2 class4 p2");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    void pkg231() {
        System.out.println("pkg2 class4 p3");
    }
}
```

following is the testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test" verbose="10" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="pkg1.Class1"/>
       <class name="pkg1.Class2"/>
       <class name="pkg2.Class4"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

following are the results.

```
pkg1 class1 p1
pkg2 class4 p1
pkg1 class1 p4
c2p2
pkg2 class4 p2
pkg1 class1 p3
pkg2 class4 p3
===== Invoked methods
    Class1.pkg111()[pri:1, instance:pkg1.Class1@4cc0edeb] 1287712235
    Class4.pkg211()[pri:1, instance:pkg2.Class4@724af044] 1917513796
    Class1.pkg121()[pri:2, instance:pkg1.Class1@4cc0edeb] 1287712235
    Class2.Pkg1c2()[pri:2, instance:pkg1.Class2@39aeed2f] 967765295
    Class4.pkg221()[pri:2, instance:pkg2.Class4@724af044] 1917513796
    Class1.pkg131()[pri:3, instance:pkg1.Class1@4cc0edeb] 1287712235
    Class4.pkg231()[pri:3, instance:pkg2.Class4@724af044] 1917513796
=====
```

Comment: Seems you have messed up your `@Test` code, `testng.xml` & `console` output all together while framing the Question. 1. You have imported only `package pkg1` where as your `testng.xml` mentions `pkg2` 2. Your console output contains `pkg2 class4 p2` and `pkg2 class4 p3` Sysouts, so you need to show us the code of `pkg2 class4`. Thanks

Comment: Updated the question with correct classes.

Comment: @Dev: can you help?

Comment: I am so sorry. I missed out working for an Answer for you today. Can you please wait till tomorrow first hour? Thanks

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`@Test(priority = X)` has a global scope and the priority order will belong to all methods of the suite.

Just replace `@Test(priority = X)` by `@Test(dependsOnMethods = "X")`.

Comment: ok this got me results as i wanted. But this will also introduce the unwanted dependency in the code and which is not recommended. i have more than 10 classes with 8 methods in each class in my Automation script. is there any other way where i can execute them sequentially without using dependency????

Comment: Just remove the `priority`, which is a dependency feature too. Or use the appropriate one (`dependsOnMethods`).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using `preserve-order` attribute as below:

```
<test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

Make this change and check whether this helps or not.

Comment: I have replaced _group-by-instances="true"_ with _preserve-order="true"_. it got me the same output as before. Dint work for me..

Comment: `preserve-order` and `group-by-instances` cannot fix `priority`order because `priority` is a more important dependency feature: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/CHANGES.txt#L70